# Create a nested child node in Firebase using Firebase 3.x

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase 3.6

My Firebase DB is blank. I want to add a key name users. Under users again I want to add one user with its UID and set User Details Dictionary as value for key UID.

```
            let user: User = User()
            user.firstName = "ABC"
            user.lastName = "XYZ"
            user.phoneNumber = "123"


        let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        dbRef.child("users").setValue(user1.uid) { (error, ref) -> Void in
            let stri: String = user1.uid
            dbRef.child(stri).setValue(user)
        }
```

[image]

This is the code. But it throws an exception.  Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Dictionary instead of User object..

```
  var user = [String:String]()
  user["firstname"] = "ABC"
  user["lastname"] = "XYZ"
  user["phone"] = "123"

  let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

  dbRef.child("users").setValue(user1.uid) { (error, ref) -> Void in
      let stri = user1.uid
      dbRef.child(stri).setValue(user)
  }
```